# Mongo - Fundamental Ignorance... S

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, serialization

This line fails with a message: unsupported filter: (Serialization(cnt) == Serialization(cnt))???.

If I remove the && x.cnt == x.cnt it works fine.
Do I have to define custom or even tell the code what the standard serialization is on the class. 
Saves fine and reads if I don't do the above just x.cnt == 4

### What am I doing wrong or not understanding? -- thanks

```
   var tests = await db.GetCollection<ctest>("ctests").Find(x => x.cnt == 4     && x.cnt == x.cnt).ToListAsync();
```

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace MongoDBTest
    {

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

        private async void btnConsultantTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IMongoDatabase db = PreLoad.MongoDB;

            var ctestCollection = db.GetCollection<ctest>("ctests");

            var entity = new ctest { cnt = 4, id = 77};
            await ctestCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
            var tests = await db.GetCollection<ctest>("ctests").Find(x => x.cnt == 4 && x.cnt == x.cnt).ToListAsync();
            ctest ctester = tests.FirstOrDefault<ctest>();

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace MongoDBTest
{
    public class ctest
    {
             [BsonId]
        public int id { get; set; }
       public int anint { get; set; }
       public int cnt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the x.cnt == x.cnt?

Comment: It's obviously a test -- why would this error out?  if I joined tables and referenced property against property I would get this error...

Comment: What happens, for giggles, when you do x.cnt == x.anint?

Comment: Thanks -- good question --Unsupported filter: (Serialization(cnt) == Serialization(anint)).

Comment: Seems this is not totally unique...http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2015-06/msg00520.html

Comment: I guess I should mention this is with the C# 2 driver -- perhaps the bug is there?